# CSS DIV AUTO fill Height and Width (overflow is Scroll bar)

Tags: html, fill

Any one can HELP me ?

I tried many Days, and many source.
But, I can find answer.

- I need creat 4 DIV by CSS.
- Header div is 100px, and always in TOP.
- Footer div is 100px, and always in BOTTOM 
  (also, if client browser resize, it always in Bottom, no change Layout)
- Left div is Width 200px (Height: auto fill)
- MAIN div is AUTO fill Height and Width (overflow is Scroll bar)

Please, help me FULL CODE HTML, or CSS, or Javascript.
Because, I not good for CSS...

please, see this picture:
[image: example]

here is an example of the html, it's ok in FF but not IE

```
<html>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div style="position: absolute; background: #faa; height: 100px; top: 0px; width: 100%;">
        header
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background: #afa; top: 100px; bottom: 100px; left: 0;
        width: 100px;">
        left
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background: #afa; top: 100px; bottom: 100px; right: 0;
        width: 100px;">
        right
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background: #faa; height: 100px; bottom: 0px; width: 100%;">
        footer
    </div>
    <div style="position: absolute; background: #aaf; bottom: 100px; left: 100px; top: 100px;
        right: 100px; overflow: auto;">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>
            <p>Aliquam tincidunt tempor
            velit quis volutpat. Nulla pharetra pulvinar arcu sed lacinia.</p>
            <p> Nulla ultrices aliquet
            sem, vitae commodo elit condimentum ut. Nulla consectetur facilisis nibh, et tempus
            purus pellentesque nec. Ut eu nibh ut arcu mattis luctus. </p>
            <p>Cras at interdum quam.
            Pellentesque imperdiet mi vitae felis sollicitudin iaculis. </p>
            <p>Maecenas accumsan tortor
            neque, at posuere felis. Quisque ultricies mi quis dolor pellentesque elementum.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GPhJU)

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Maybe with a JSFiddle

Comment: I don't know where to post my code.
I save it in this file .htm.
it ok on FF, but not on IE.
http://nguyentaison.com/css_auto_fill.htm

Comment: What's the problem in IE, can you show a screenshot?

Comment: nguyentaison.com/errorIE/01.jpg error on IE8. no scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/QXKtm/3/

HTML

```
<header></header>
<div id="container">
    <section id="menu"></section>
    <section id="content"></section>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header, footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
}

footer {
    bottom: 0;
}

header {
    top: 0;
}

#container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}

#menu, #content {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;

}

#menu {
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left;
}

#content {
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 220px;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank so much for quick help me. I so so ill with this problem. I tried your code, but it HTML5 ? CSS 3 ? it not run on IE 8. Can you help me Code for HTML4, and IE 6,7,8 ??? Thank so so much again (^_^) You are very good man ! This is firt time, i try to ask on a forum, you are my angle (^_^)